# Questions about scattering matrix theory of non-free particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, interactions, s-matrix-theory, phonons

Hi，I have a problem for scattering matrix theory.
Currently, the book I've read is about collision between free particles.

What if collision between non-free particles? For example, in lattice, only certain quasi-momentum of phonon satisfying Bloch equation. When two phonons collide, how to treat it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in principle only certain quasi-momentum are allowed. However, the spacing between allowed quasi-momenta will scale inversely with the number of atoms in the solid. Since most solids contain a lot of atoms, the spacing will be very tiny and the spectrum of quasi-momenta is treated as continuous.

The main difference between phonons and free particles is that momentum must be conserved, but quasi-momentum only has to be conserved up to a reciprocal lattice vector. This leads to [umklapp scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umklapp_scattering), which can lead to counter-intuitive results. For example two phonons can interact and scatter in the "wrong" direction (as shown in the link).

Comment: What if the solids contain only very limited number of atoms?  How to treat this case?

Comment: I mean for particles moving in finite lattice, where the momentum must be conserved